# Extract subterm from term's list

Tags: prolog

my problem is probably easy to solve but today i have one of this 'poor' days.
I am trying to extract host from url. Function parse_url comes from library(url).

Here is a function:

```
extract_host(X) :-
    parse_url("http://hostexample.org/index.html", X).
```

Output:

> X = [protocol(http), host('hostexample.org'), path('/index.html')].

How can I get only **hostexample.org** from it?

Edit (working function):

```
extract_host(HN) :-
    parse_url("http://hostexample.org/index.html", X),
    memberchk(host(HN), X).
```

Comment: In the general case, the host might not be the second argument. In that case use `memberchk(host(HostName), X)` after the call to `parse_url/2`.

Comment: memberchk works good! thanks gusbro

Comment: @gusbro please make this an answer so this question can be marked as solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the host you should use [memberchk/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=memberchk/2) on the list unified by the call to `parse_url/2` as the host may or may not be the second argument of it (the documentation of `parse_url/2` does not state the order of the arguments in that list).

```
extract_host(Url, HostName):-
    parse_url(Url, LParsed),
    memberchk(host(HostName), LParsed).
```

and query `extract_host("http://hostexample.org/index.html", Host).`